# How to remove default iOS form styles

Tags: ios, css, mailchimp

I recently launched a landing page for a new website. But on iOS, the inputs fields are ignoring the padding of the container and the subscribe button looks completely different. How can I fix this?

View the landing page: [signup.sketchtricks.com](http://signup.sketchtricks.com)

Screenshot on iOS: [cl.ly/image/0y0P0m0J3a3X](http://cl.ly/image/0y0P0m0J3a3X)

Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

Add...

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
border-radius: 0;
```

...to the affected selectors in your css.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for the subscribe button, for the input fields I used:

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;